# Port forwarding not working

Tags: server, 22.04, iptables, firewall

I have a machine on my home network I am trying to port forward (for rust if that helps) and I need to get these done

TCP: 27015, 27036, 28016, 28083
UDP: 27015, 27031-27036, 28015

I have allowed all of these through UFW but the port is still showing closed through port checkers and there is a service running (the game server). I also tried going through iptables but either or are not doing the job and I do not understand what I am missing here.

I am newish to ubuntu server and have  a very small basic knowledge base on it.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to access it over the Internet, or is this internal only?

Comment: Define "port forwarding".  Are you port forwarding at the Internet router to your system or from your system elsewhere?  If you are using port checkers on the Internet, you have to port forward **at the router** to your system that's running this server on those ports. and that's not an Ubuntu thing

Comment: Allow external connection (internal works). I guess i meant to say attempting to open ports through ubuntu’s firewall is not working i set them to be allowed through UFW and in doing so upon testing ports with port check tools with the service running the port is still closed. Although the panel and terminal it self can be accessed externally and their ports are open